# Custom cookie lasts 5 seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, drupal, drupal-8

I'm trying to set a cookie to show a modal only once. I've tried using jQuery cookies like this:

`$.cookie("cookie", "0", {expires: date});`

where date has been tried like a integer and like a summatory of current date + integer:

```
var date = new Date();
date.setDate(date.getDate() + 15);
```

I've also tried with js.cookie added in my src/js files in my gulpconfig.js, with the "fancy" code:

`Cookies.set('cookiename','0',{expires: date}`

But same result. I close the modal and if I refresh inmediately (first 5 seconds), a console.log() would show its value is correctly changed to 1, and if I keep refreshing, it keeps resetting its expiration 5 more seconds, but if I wait this seconds and refresh, the value is 0 again and the modal comes back.

Comment: If you are only including `$cookie` in page for this use case, using localStorage would be simpler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I had to whitelist the cookie in the EU Cookie Compliance module... Didn't know it would disable functional cookies by default.

Answer (score 0):

```
let date = new Date();
date = date.getDate(); //extracting cuurent date from date object
date = date + 15 ; //adding 15 more days to it.

$.cookie("cookie", 0, { expires : date }); //cookie expires after 15 days.
```

To delete the cookie

```
$.removeCookie("test");
```